# Delete subdocument from array

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Given below data, I want to delete all sub-documents in `"data"` where `"k" == "c"`. That's my code:

```
var query = Query.EQ("templateId", "537c6648d7d6bd0a68a34918");
var update = Update.Pull("data", new BsonDocument() { { "k", "c" } });
MyMongoCollection.Update(query, update);
```

So what happens is that exactly 1 document is affected and the updating stops. I verified the query and it returns all documents as expected. Just with the pull-update, it breaks.

What could be wrong?

WriteConcern has no error. The query alone returns 3 docs and the WriteConcern has 1 doc affected.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("537c85a2d7d6bd0a68a3491b"),
    "templateId" : "537c6648d7d6bd0a68a34918",
    "data" : [ 
        {"k" : "b", "v" : "111"}, 
        {"k" : "a", "v" : "222"}, 
        {"k" : "c", "v" : "333"}
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("537d6a41d7d6bd0608cb27a4"),
    "templateId" : "537c6648d7d6bd0a68a34918",
    "data" : [ 
        {"k" : "b", "v" : "111"}, 
        {"k" : "a", "v" : "222"}, 
        {"k" : "c", "v" : "333"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating multiple documents you should set the [update flags](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.0/html/7dbd2e20-c388-b5b8-957b-0ad329ccf832.htm) to `Multi`:

```
MyMongoCollection.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Multi);
```

This will remove subdocuments from all documents.

From the MongoDB documentation:

> By default, the update() method updates a single document that matches
>   its selection criteria. Call the method with the multi option set to
>   true to update multiple documents.